# Decorating type level list with extra information from type level map

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families, type-level-computation, data-kinds

I have this heterogenous list which has its type reflect the types of the values it contains. I can convert all of the elements to strings by checking that every type contained satisfies a constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}   

import GHC.Exts
import GHC.TypeLits

import Data.Proxy

type family AllSatisfy (f :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where
    AllSatisfy f '[] = ()
    AllSatisfy f (x ': xs) = (f x, AllSatisfy f xs)

data HList (as :: [*]) where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

type family Keys (xs :: [(a, b)]) :: [a] where
    Keys '[] = '[]
    Keys ( '(a, b) ': xs) = a ': Keys xs

type family Values (xs :: [(a, b)]) :: [b] where
    Values '[] = '[]
    Values ( '(a, b) ': xs) = b ': Values xs

showHList :: AllSatisfy Show xs => HList xs -> [String]
showHList HNil = []
showHList (HCons x xs) = show x : showHList xs
```

What I'd like to be able to do is specify some extra information via a type level association list, which is indexed by the types in the HList. Something like:

```
showWithKey :: forall (keyMap :: [(*, Symbol)]) (b :: Symbol) (rest :: [(*, Symbol)]).
               (AllSatisfy Show (Keys keyMap)
               ,AllSatisfy KnownSymbol (Values keyMap)
               ) =>
               Proxy keyMap -> HList (Keys keyMap) -> [(String, String)]
showWithKey _ HNil = []
showWithKey _ (HCons (x :: a) (xs :: HList as)) =
    let p = (Proxy @keyMap) :: Proxy ( '(a, b) ': rest )
    in (show x, symbolVal (Proxy @b)) : (showWithKey (Proxy @rest) xs)
```

Now, it's clear to see that if `(Keys keyMap)` is non-empty, then `keyMap`, but GHC struggles to figured this out:

```
Could not deduce: keyMap ~ ('(a, b) : rest)
      from the context: (AllSatisfy Show (Keys keyMap),
                         AllSatisfy KnownSymbol (Values keyMap))
        bound by the type signature for:
                   showWithKey :: (AllSatisfy Show (Keys keyMap),
                                   AllSatisfy KnownSymbol (Values keyMap)) =>
                                  Proxy keyMap -> HList (Keys keyMap) -> [(String, String)]
      or from: Keys keyMap ~ (a : as)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   HCons :: forall a (as :: [ghc-prim-0.5.0.0:GHC.Types.*]).
                            a -> HList as -> HList (a : as),
                 in an equation for ‘showWithKey’
      ‘keyMap’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          showWithKey :: forall (keyMap :: [(ghc-prim-0.5.0.0:GHC.Types.*,
                                             Symbol)]) (b :: Symbol) (rest :: [(ghc-prim-0.5.0.0:GHC.Types.*,
                                                                                Symbol)]).
                         (AllSatisfy Show (Keys keyMap),
                          AllSatisfy KnownSymbol (Values keyMap)) =>
                         Proxy keyMap -> HList (Keys keyMap) -> [(String, String)]
      Expected type: Proxy ('(a, b) : rest)
        Actual type: Proxy keyMap
```

How can I rewrite this so that GHC can figure things out?

Comment: You cannot with a type family - the kind `(Symbol, *)` is inhabited by infinitely many types which are not of the form `'( _, _)` (e.g. `Any`, `Any Any`, etc) - `Keys` and `Values` must both become *classes*, in which the body of the class *assumes* the truth of the constraints in the head and context, as opposed to *requiring* them as in the case of a type family application. If you want to access these proofs outside of the class, you will have to have a function in the class which constructs a value level representation of such a proof (a GADT, typically).

Answer (score 1):

Taking some cues what user2407038 said, I created a concrete representation of the `depMap` type and then created a type class to describe a not-quite-singleton-but-at-least-canonical value from the type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import GHC.Exts
import GHC.TypeLits

import Data.Proxy

type family AllSatisfy (f :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where
    AllSatisfy f '[] = ()
    AllSatisfy f (x ': xs) = (f x, AllSatisfy f xs)

data HList (as :: [*]) where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

type family Keys (xs :: [(a, b)]) :: [a] where
    Keys '[] = '[]
    Keys ( '(a, b) ': xs) = a ': Keys xs

type family Values (xs :: [(a, b)]) :: [b] where
    Values '[] = '[]
    Values ( '(a, b) ': xs) = b ': Values xs

showHList :: AllSatisfy Show xs => HList xs -> [String]
showHList HNil = []
showHList (HCons x xs) = show x : showHList xs

data SKeyMap :: [(*, Symbol)] -> * where
  SKeyNil :: SKeyMap '[]
  SKeyCons :: Proxy a -> Proxy s -> SKeyMap xs -> SKeyMap ( '(a, s) ': xs )

class KnownKeyMap (keyMap :: [(*, Symbol)]) where
    sKeyMap :: SKeyMap keyMap


instance KnownKeyMap '[] where
    sKeyMap = SKeyNil

instance KnownKeyMap keyMap => KnownKeyMap ( '(a, s) ': keyMap ) where
    sKeyMap = SKeyCons Proxy Proxy sKeyMap

showWithKey' :: forall (keyMap :: [(*, Symbol)]) .
               (AllSatisfy Show (Keys keyMap)
               ,AllSatisfy KnownSymbol (Values keyMap)
               ) =>
               SKeyMap keyMap -> HList (Keys keyMap) -> [(String, String)]
showWithKey' SKeyNil HNil = []
showWithKey' (SKeyCons _ sp skRest) (HCons (x :: a) (xs :: HList as)) =
    (show x, symbolVal sp) : (showWithKey' skRest xs)

showWithKey :: forall (keyMap :: [(*, Symbol)]) .
               (KnownKeyMap keyMap
               ,AllSatisfy Show (Keys keyMap)
               ,AllSatisfy KnownSymbol (Values keyMap)
               ) =>
               HList (Keys keyMap) -> [(String, String)]
showWithKey = showWithKey' (sKeyMap @keyMap)
```